# JavaFX window setTitle

Tags: javafx, window, title

I have a main class which is the following:

```
public class Window extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage foablak) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Foablak.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        foablak.setScene(scene);
        foablak.setWidth(900);
        foablak.setHeight(700);
        foablak.setResizable(false);
        foablak.setTitle("Window");

        foablak.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

How can I update the Title of the from another .java class without closing the window and open a new one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exposing properties using `static`, just for the sake of exposing, *may be* considered as a bad design. You have different ways to achieve the same, for example, expose a method from the Window class which sets the stage title.

```
public class Window extends Application {

    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage foablak) throws Exception {
        stage = foablak;
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Foablak.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        foablak.setScene(scene);
        foablak.setWidth(900);
        foablak.setHeight(700);
        foablak.setResizable(false);
        foablak.setTitle("Window");

        foablak.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void setStageTitle(String newTitle) {
        stage.setTitle(newTitle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.  Inside of your `Application.start()` method, save a reference to your primary `Stage` that you can access elsewhere, and then call `Stage.setTitle()`.

```
class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MyApplication.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        // ...
    }

}

MyApplication.primaryStage.setTitle("New Title");
```

As an aside, I would avoid calling your class `Window`, as that is the name of one of the JavaFX classes.

Answer (score 1):

The following may not be the solution you were looking for, but it might be useful for some of the developers:

- Scenario: There is only 1 JavaFX app; The app needs to be run
  multiple times; You want to differentiate who is running the app
- Attention: Pay attention of the running order of the Main and
  Controller class
- Solution: i. In the Controller Class, declare a private static variable, e.g., private static String strWho; ii. Expose strWho by providing a getter method. e.g.:  public static String getWho(){
      return strWho;
  }; iii. Implement the initialize method for the Controller, and based on your need, assign a distinct value each time you run the JavaFX app. eg., @FXML
  public void initialize() {
      strWho = "you need to have logic here, to have a distinct value each time you run the app";
  }
- In the Main start method, right before you call the stage.show, set the title. eg:
     primaryStage.setTitle(Controller.getWho()));
     primaryStage.show();
- One way to implement the logic for distinct value of the strWho each time you run the app: You can have a TextInputDialog in the Controller's initialize method, to accept user input, by asking for a name etc.

Comment: no static scope anywhere, please - it's extremely rare that you really want  it (and definitely not in the OP's context)